# Firebird 2.5 database compatibility between 32bit and 64bit versions

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Are there any known issues with database compatibility (GDB files) when switching Firebird Classic server from 64bit to 32bit or vice versa? I found information, that databases are compatible among Classic and Superserver, but this information was for Firebird 2.1 and I didn't find anything newer - http://firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/install210.html#install-model

Comment: The equivalent documentation for 2.5 is http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/qsg25-classic-or-super.html which says _"Notice that you can always switch to another model later; your applications and databases will keep functioning like before. The differences are in the servers, not in the databases."_

Comment: If your database ends in `gdb`, it can also be a very old database (extension `fdb` is normal), if you have a very old database (ODS 11.0 or earlier), then 32 bit vs 64 bit can matter and you really need to backup and restore (which will also upgrade the ODS).

Comment: GDB file extension is not recommended starting with WinXP, could be nasty surprises around OS System Recovery feature / there is this tech info in Russian if you would care read it via www.translate.ru  // http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq353/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The databases are compatible between *Classic*, *SuperClassic* and *SuperServer* as well as *32bit* and *64bit* within same Firebird version (between versions it's recommended (needed since FB3) to do backup & restore). It's the same code, same structure, just different execution model.

Comment: The exception is 32 bit vs 64 bit in versions before Firebird 2.1, and when switching between big-endian and little-endian architectures.